# Конвертация ArrayList в двухмерный массив

Tags: java

Написал код по конвертации `ArrayList` в двухмерный массив,но тест проваливается. Прошу помочь найти ошибку.

```
public class ConvertList2Array {
    public static int[][] toArray(List<Integer> list, int cells) {
        int groups = (int) Math.ceil((double) list.size() / cells);
        int[][] array = new int[groups][cells];
        int row = 0, cell = 0, index = 0;
        for (Integer num: list) {
            while(cell < 3 && row < 3) {
                array[row][cell] = num++;
                cell++;
            }
            row++;
            cell = 0;
        }
        return array;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
        int[][] rsl = toArray(list, 3);
        for (int[] row : rsl) {
            for (int cell : row) {
                System.out.print(cell + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}

public class ConvertList2ArrayTest {

    @Test
    public void when7ElementsThen9() {
        ConvertList2Array list = new ConvertList2Array();
        int[][] result = list.toArray(
                Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
                3
        );
        int[][] expect = {
                {1, 2, 3},
                {4, 5, 6},
                {7, 0, 0}
        };
        assertThat(result, is(expect));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так.

`ConvertList2Array`:

```
package com.somepackage;

import java.util.List;

public class ConvertList2Array {

    public static int[][] toArray(List<Integer> list, int cells) {
        int groups = (int) Math.ceil((double) list.size() / cells);
        int[][] array = new int[groups][cells];
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for (Integer n: list) {
            array[i][j] = n;
            if (++j >= cells) {
                i++;
                j = 0;
            }
        }
        return array;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
        int[][] rsl = toArray(list, 3);
        for (int[] row : rsl) {
            for (int cell : row) {
                System.out.print(cell + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

`ConvertList2ArrayTest`:

```
package com.somepackage;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

public class ConvertList2ArrayTest {

    @Test
    public void when7ElementsThen9() {
        ConvertList2Array list = new ConvertList2Array();
        int[][] result = list.toArray(
                Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
                3
        );
        int[][] expect = {
                {1, 2, 3},
                {4, 5, 6},
                {7, 0, 0}
        };
        assertTrue(Arrays.deepEquals(result, expect));
    }
}
```

Comment: через цикл for each как это сделать?

Comment: @RasimZamaltdinov Поменял.

Comment: @RasimZamaltdinov Если ответ Вам помог, то не забудьте отметить его как решение (галочка слева).